# Phantom Mapping Java 8 LocalDateTime to Joda Time

Tags: scala, phantom-dsl

I am using Phantom 1.28 with Cassandra 3.7.

I have a case class with Java 8 `LocalDateTime`:

```
case class User(
   verifiedAt: Option[LocalDateTime] = None
)
```

In phantom model:

```
class UserModel extends CassandraTable[ConcreteUserModel, User]{

object verified_at extends OptionalDateTimeColumn(this)

override def fromRow(r: Row): User = User(
    verified_at(r),  // <- compile error
)
}
```

Compile error:

```
error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : Option[com.websudos.phantom.dsl.DateTime]
[ERROR]     (which expands to)  Option[org.joda.time.DateTime]
[ERROR]  required: Option[java.time.LocalDateTime]
[ERROR]     verified_at(r),
```

I like to stick to Java 8 LocalDateTime, how can I resolve `OptionDateTimeColumn` requires joda time?  Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phantom is still JDK7 compatible, and that's been important to us, that's why Java 8 time is not directly supported, but there's separate module for it. In your build.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.websudos" %% "phantom-jdk8" % phantomVersion
)
```

Then you need to:

```
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._
import com.websudos.phantom.jdk8.dsl._

class UserModel extends CassandraTable[ConcreteUserModel, User]{

  // This will not return Option[LocalDate], it will return simply LocalDate
  object verified_at extends JdkLocalDateColumn(this)

  override def fromRow(r: Row): User = User(verified_at(r))
}
```

[**Here are**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-jdk8/src/main/scala/com/websudos/phantom/jdk8/dsl/package.scala) all the columns available for Java 8. For optional columns:

```
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._
import com.websudos.phantom.jdk8.dsl._

class UserModel extends CassandraTable[ConcreteUserModel, User]{

  object verified_at extends OptionalPrimitiveColumn[ConcreteUserModel, User, JdkLocalDate](this)

  override def fromRow(r: Row): User = User(verified_at(r))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recent version you can do it like this:

```
object date extends Col[LocalDateTime] with PrimaryKey
```